# Golang amazon s3 environment access key not found

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I created a new I-AM user set that user permission to full access for S3 then I see the environment variable for the MacBook with the correct Key and Key-ID . I then followed the amazon docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/common-examples.html#s3 to list all of my buckets and I received the error 
**Failed to list buckets EnvAccessKeyNotFound: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID or AWS_ACCESS_KEY not found in environment**

I do not know why it is not recognizing my code which is this

```
func UploadProfile() {

    svc := s3.New(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-west-2"),Credentials:credentials.NewEnvCredentials()}))
    result, err := svc.ListBuckets(&s3.ListBucketsInput{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to list buckets", err)
        return
    }

    log.Println("Buckets:")
    for _, bucket := range result.Buckets {
        log.Printf("%s : %s\n", aws.StringValue(bucket.Name), bucket.CreationDate)
    }
}
```

I had one of the variables before as **AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY** but removed the secret portion because it still gave me the same error. Any suggestions on how to fix this
[image]

Answer (score -2):

@Pablo prez,

Is *getting* credentials actually showing you the AWS keys from your env, i.e. if you run

```
creds := credentials.NewEnvCredentials()
credValue, err := creds.Get()
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

fmt.Printf("%+v", credValue)
```

will it print your keys out?

You may want to check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/credentials/ for more details.